# How can I fix the 'validation' error when using Apollo V3 to upload an image file in my Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, upload, apollo

this is my code but i get this error i useing Apollo V3 I have to upload files to the server using the Apollo version 3 library, but I have encountered the problem you can see. I select and display the file, but I have a problem when sending.

```
{
"operationName": "UploadSecureTicketFile",
"variables": {
"file": "{"body":{},"headers":{"namesAndValues":["Content-Disposition","form-data; name\u003d\"image\"; filename\u003d\"IMG-20230515-WA0001.jpg\""]}}"
},
"query": "mutation UploadSecureTicketFile($file: Upload!) { uploadSecureTicketFile: UploadSecureTicketFile(file: $file) { id } }"
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
                            try {
                                val response =
                                    apolloClient.mutation(UploadSecureTicketFileMutation(Gson().toJson(body)))
                                        .execute()
                                if (response.hasErrors()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@TicketsActivity,
                                        response.errors?.get(0)?.message,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show()
                                } else {
                                    val uploadFile = response.data?.uploadSecureTicketFile
                                    Log.e("uploadFile", uploadFile.toString())

                                }
                            } catch (e: ApolloHttpException) {
                               apolloError(e, this@TicketsActivity)
                            }
```